# MySQL: Can't create TCP/IP socket (105)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two servers (main and database). If too many accesses are made to the MySQL database from main server, I get a "Can't create TCP/IP socket (105)" error. I have try to activate/deactivate a persistent PDO connection and set the max_connections parameter very high, but that does not help. What causes this error?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/554548/several-server-errors-no-database-connect-cant-create-tcp-ip-socket-etc)

Comment: Thanks, but I also set max_connect_errors very high. When I execute "mysqladmin flush-hosts" the error remains. I think this is not the problem.

Comment: Well, we really don't have enough information to go on here and there are way too many variables that could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your web server's ("main" server's) TCP stack is running out of resources.

Some things to try:

- Configure your web server to restrict the number of simultaneously running client connections. In Apache this is the MaxClients parameter.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients  What happens when the limit is reached? other connection requests are held in the connect / listen queue.
- Check your php code to make sure you're correctly releasing your data base resources. In MySQL, it's necessary to actually retrieve your result sets. Some php code does a SELECT, and then just looks at the `rowCount()` method.
- Make sure you aren't constructing PDO objects in a loop.
- Use the `netstat` command to figure out who's hogging ports.

Answer (score -3):

Try to check `max_connect_errors` parameter. Most likely your host is under attack or there is some bad designed application that could not connect and reaches limit of attempts.

Oh, don't forget to restart mysqld then.

Hope it would helps!